# CSS: Adding Hover Overlay causes div to appear at the top of the screen as well

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working with a CSS Overlay for an image, trying to get text to display when the image is hovered. I have it working, but for some reason, the text is also all appearing as a blob above the gallery. I think it's to do with the position tag I'm using, but I'm not sure how to reproduce exactly. Code below + CSB:

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-moore-qeki7

gallery

```
                   {
                    data.map((edge) => (
                        <div key={edge} className={styles.imgHov}>
                            <Img 
                                fluid={edge.node.data.one} 
                                className={styles.image}
                            />
                            <div className={styles.overlay} key={edge}>

                                <p className={styles.text}>{edge.node.data.item_one}</p>
                                <p className={styles.text}>{edge.node.data.item_two}</p>
                                
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    ))
                    }
```

css

```
.imgHov:hover{
    position: relative;
}

.image{
    width: 25vw;
    height: 25vw;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 40%;
    width: 60%; 
    background-color: pink;
    height: 60%;
    width: 25vw;
}

.overlay .text{
    color: white;
    font-family: Geomanist;
}
```

Comment: `position: absolute;` ?

Comment: Thanks @Greedo, yes, but I need that to have .overlay display over the image, no?

Comment: Please include your HTML that gets generated, along with the CSS in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what is happening and be able to help.

Comment: Thanks @FluffyKitten, I included the Html above. It's a javascript (Gatsby) project that loops through a list of images and displays each one by one.

Comment: so to clarify, you want to show the `.overlay` div on mouse hover?

Comment: Yes, but if you could include it as a snippet in a working example, it would make it a lot easier for us to help because then we can see the problem “in action” :) UPDATE: fyi  you can add a snippet in the editor using the `[<>]` button on the toolbar.

Comment: Yes @Greedo that's right!

Comment: @FluffyKitten I'll make one now!

Comment: insert html here

Comment: @FluffyKitten I've made a CodeSandbox minimal reproduction. Link here and edited in question! https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-moore-qeki7

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov here is a link: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-moore-qeki7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I translated your app in normal HTML, i think this should meet your requirements :)

```css
.imgHov{
    position: relative;
        width: 25vw;
    height: 25vw;
}

.image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.overlay{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 40%;
    width: 60%; 
    background-color: pink;
    height: 60%;
    width: 25vw;
}

.overlay .text{
    color: white;
    font-family: Geomanist;
}

.imgHov:hover .overlay {
   display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="imgHov">
  <img class="image" src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/92E141F8-36E4-4331-BB2EE42AC8674DD3_source.jpg"/>
  <div class="overlay">
      <p class="text">item one</p>
      <p class="text">item two</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Greedo! THis works. It was the display property in the end I think. Thanks for your help :)